# Vb.net time delay happening before it is supposed to do

Tags: vb.net

I want this all to happen at the same time but the pause in the code happens before the button changes color how do i make it so it happens afterwards.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    Randomize()

    Dim Buttonnum As Integer = CInt(Int((9 * Rnd()) + 1))

    Select Case Buttonnum
        Case "1"
            Button1.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Case "2"
            Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Case "3"
            Button3.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Case "4"
            Button4.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Case "5"
            Button5.BackColor = Color.Pink
        Case "6"
            Button6.BackColor = Color.Purple
        Case "7"
            Button7.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Case "8"
            Button8.BackColor = Color.Violet
        Case "9"
            Button9.BackColor = Color.Green
    End Select

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    MsgBox("I")



End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Application.DoEvents` after the selection finishes. I know this works for message box text, it may update the color too.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure if you're able to but it would be greatly appreciated if you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the Up/Down arrows by my answer. It will give me enough rep to add a bounty to one of my questions that doesn't have an answer yet.